# Group by fields from several tables in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, group-by

I have this code:

## 1

```
from peron in db.Persons
join room in db.Rooms on peron.Room.Id equals room.Id
join passport in db.Passports on peron.Passport.Id equals passport.Id
select new {peron.Fio, room.Number, passport.Address};
```

It translates to this:

## 2

```
SELECT [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
[Extent2].[Number] AS [Number], 
[Extent3].[Address] AS [Address]
FROM   [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rooms] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Room_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Passport_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

How I can change my linq query, so it will be generating this:

## 3

```
SELECT ...
FROM   [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rooms] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Room_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[Passport_Id] = [Extent3].[Id]}
GROUP BY [Extent1].[Fio], [Extent3].[Num]
```

I tried to use GroupBy extension method but I can't get desired result. I can use translation #2 and then apply GroupBy on client-side, but I would like have translation with GROUP BY like #3.
Thanks.

Comment: What _is_ your desired result?  You redacted the columns that you are returning form the desired query so there's no way to know what you are expecting.

Comment: What about `passport.Address` ?

Comment: I would like have GROUP BY in the translation of linq query.
For example "GROUP BY [Extent1].[Fio], [Extent3].[Num]"
How I can get this in my query by linq provider?

"passport.Address" this can be string propery of Passport entity.

Comment: It;s important to know what _columns_ you want in the result - I'm assuming you're aggregating something since you're using `GROUP BY` (or else `GROUP BY` is not the correct tool for what you want to do).  You can't include the same columns from the first two queries since they are not all in the GROUP BY clause. Maybe you want `DISTINCT` instead?

Comment: I want to have peron.Fio, room.Number, passport.Address, count(peron.Fio)
and group by peron.Fio with any property from other table. So I need group by, not distinct.
Thanks

Comment: Is it important that you get the exact SQL, or is it important that you get the *result*? I'm assuming it's the latter but the way you worded your question makes me want to clarify it. Also, do you have navigation properties in your model between Person, Room, and Passport?

Comment: It's the test example. I would like to learn how I can make group by query by queryable provider.
In this example I have Person with (Id int, Fio string, Room Room, Passport Passport) It can be seen in code sample #1.

Now I can get the desired result by query #1 with postprocessing by GroupBy extension (after ToList() invoking). But I would like to use query without postprocessing in the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
var qry = from peron in db.Persons
join room in db.Rooms on peron.Room.Id equals room.Id
join passport in db.Passports on peron.Passport.Id equals passport.Id
select new {peron.Fio, room.Name, passport.Number, Count = 0};

qry = qry.GroupBy(l => new {l.Fio, l.Number})
      .Select(l => new {l.Key.Fio, Name = "", l.Key.Number, Count = l.Count()});
```

I got the following sql

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Fio], 
    N'' AS [C2], 
    [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [Number], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Fio] AS [K1], 
        [Extent2].[Number] AS [K2], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM  [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Passport_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Room_Id] IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[Fio], [Extent2].[Number]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

However if I replace Name = "" to **l.FirstOrDefault().Name** I get a more complex query

```
var qry = from peron in db.Persons
join room in db.Rooms on peron.Room.Id equals room.Id
join passport in db.Passports on peron.Passport.Id equals passport.Id
select new {peron.Fio, room.Name, passport.Number, Count = 0};
qry = qry.GroupBy(l => new {l.Fio, l.Number}).Select(l => new {l.Key.Fio, l.FirstOrDefault().Name, l.Key.Number, Count = l.Count()});


SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Project4].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
    [Project4].[C1] AS [C2], 
    [Project4].[Number] AS [Number], 
    [Project4].[C2] AS [C3]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project3].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
        [Project3].[Number] AS [Number], 
        [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[People] AS [Extent6]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent6].[Passport_Id] = [Extent7].[Id]
            WHERE ([Extent6].[Room_Id] IS NOT NULL) AND (([Project3].[Fio] = [Extent6].[Fio]) OR (([Project3].[Fio] IS NULL) AND ([Extent6].[Fio] IS NULL))) AND (([Project3].[Number] = [Extent7].[Number]) OR (([Project3].[Number] IS NULL) AND ([Extent7].[Number] IS NULL)))) AS [C2]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Distinct1].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
            [Distinct1].[Number] AS [Number], 
            (SELECT TOP (1) 
                [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name]
                FROM   [dbo].[People] AS [Extent3]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rooms] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[Room_Id] = [Extent4].[Id]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent3].[Passport_Id] = [Extent5].[Id]
                WHERE (([Distinct1].[Fio] = [Extent3].[Fio]) OR (([Distinct1].[Fio] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[Fio] IS NULL))) AND (([Distinct1].[Number] = [Extent5].[Number]) OR (([Distinct1].[Number] IS NULL) AND ([Extent5].[Number] IS NULL)))) AS [C1]
            FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
                [Extent1].[Fio] AS [Fio], 
                [Extent2].[Number] AS [Number]
                FROM  [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Passports] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Passport_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
                WHERE [Extent1].[Room_Id] IS NOT NULL
            )  AS [Distinct1]
        )  AS [Project3]
    )  AS [Project4]}
```

How I can fix the issue with **l.FirstOrDefault().Name**?
I can't add room.Name field to grouped fields...

My test entities:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fio { get; set; }
        public Room Room { get; set; }
        public Passport Passport { get; set; }
    }

    public class Room
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Passport
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }
```

If I use this:

```
var qry = from peron in db.Persons
join room in db.Rooms on peron.Room.Id equals room.Id
join passport in db.Passports on peron.Passport.Id equals passport.Id
                    select new {peron.Fio, room.Name, passport.Number, Count = 0};
qry = qry.GroupBy(l => new {l.Fio, l.Name, l.Number}).Select(l => new {l.Key.Fio, l.Key.Name, l.Key.Number, Count = l.Count()});
```

I have the simple sql query, but I can't use room.Name in GROUP BY section...
Thanks.